# What are the rules of natural healing?

Tags: healing, microlite20

I've read a few times the [core rules of Microlite20](http://1d4chan.org/wiki/Microlite20), and the [Expert Rules](http://arthur.jfmi.net/m20/Microlite20ExpertRules.pdf), but didn't find a place where it explained how PCs healed naturally. What rules should I use for that? The ones in the official SRD? Are there any popular house rules for this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the "Mini 20" implementation of the Microlite20 rules (included in [The Microlite20 RPG Collection](http://www.retroroleplaying.com/content/microlite20-rpg-collection) PDF), **1d4 hit points are recovered per day of rest**. The Microlite11 iteration suggests **1/2-level, rounded up,** instead.

Comment: Thanks, I'll do it the Microlite11 way. Though using a variation of the Mini20 way (using 1d6 instead of 1d4) would be neat too. Food for thought.

Answer (score 1):

Microlite20 "[Golden edition](https://microlite20.org/2015/06/07/microlite20-golden-edition-available-for-download/)" has rules for natural healing as well:

> **Natural Healing**
>   Characters heal naturally at a rate of 1HP and 1STR per day of rest, 3HP and STR
>   bonus (minimum of 1 if no STR bonus) if complete bed rest (doing nothing for an
>   entire day). For each complete week of bed rest, the character can add his STR. In
>   both cases above, the character must have adequate food, water, and sleep.

**Hovewer, this is not so important.**

Microlite20 is designed to be quick and easy to play. It gives to the GM a foundation for basics, and the GM is supposed to make quick ad-hoc adjudications for all the rest.

When adjudicating natural healing, answer these two questions:

- How potent natural healing is?
- Does it scale with level and/or stats?

Then you get all the possible options, how many hit points per day can you get due to natural healing:

- 1d4 (not so potent, does not scale)
- 1d6 (more potent, does not scale)
- 1d6 + STR bonus (even more potent, scales with STR)
- flat number (more stable, does not scale)
- 1/2-level, rounded up (not so potent but more stable, scales with level)
- equals to level (more potent, scales with level), etc.

As a GM, you can also decide that natural healing in your game is not the thing at all — in this case you say to your players, that one needs more than few days to completely heal a stab wound, or has to use magic. Just be consistent with your choices.